# Laravel Nova Value Icon change

Tags: laravel-nova

Spending an hour on searching how to adjust or hide the icon on a single laravel nova metric value... How can I remove/change or style that blue icon?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
public $icon = false;
```

Hides the icon...

Answer (score 0):

```
public $icon = 'globe';
```

You were close, you simply need to pass the icon name.

Nova utilizes the free icon set Heroicons UI from designer Steve Schoger. Feel free to use these icons to match the look and feel of Nova's built-in icons.

Comment: correct, to change them this is the approach. For hiding it is the above one.